# Problem while remeshing in sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting, remesh

[image: axe]

How do I remove those "holes" in the handle?

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh seems super destroyed so I'm not sure it will work but you can try that:

Switch to edges select mode in *Edit* mode, then *Select > Select All by Trait > Non Manifold*, then <kbd>F</kbd> to fill:

[image]

Or select all in *Edit* mode and *Mesh > Clean Up > Fill Holes* and play with the amount of *Sides* in the *Operator* box:

[image]

Comment: Oh my, the first operation actually worked, thank you so much!